# Brown measure of left shift operator

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, random-matrices, free-probability

Let $L$ be the left shift operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ with trace $\tau(T) := \langle T \delta_0, \delta_0 \rangle$.

How can I show that the Brown measure of $L$ is the uniform measure on the unit circle?

The Brown measure is defined as follows:  For each $z \in \mathbb{C}$ define $\nu_{z}$ to be the spectral measure of the (self-adjoint) operator $(L - z)^*(L-z)$.  Then let $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \log x \,d\nu_z(x).$$  Then the Brown measure is defined as $$\mu_L := \frac{1}{2\pi} \Delta f,$$ where the Laplacian is taken in the sense of distributions.  Motivation for the definition can be found at [Terence Tao's notes on the circular law for random matrices](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/254a-notes-8-the-circular-law/).

Edit: posted at math stackexchange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258115/brown-measure-of-left-shift-operator

Comment: What's the relevance of $\tau (T)$ for this question?

Comment: To address my own comment, I guess what you're saying is that $\nu_z$ is defined as the spectral measure $d\|E(x)\delta_0\|^2$ of $\delta_0$ ("the spectral measure," meaning a positive measure on $\mathbb C$, is not unambiguously defined)?

Comment: The spectral measure of $L$ wrt $\delta_0$ is Lebesgue measure on $S^1$. Using this as your starting point, it should be possible to work everything out explicitly. I believe your question would have been better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was having trouble computing the spectral measure of $(L-z)^*(L-z)$, however.  Is that still easy?  And fair enough, I posted here because the only other references to Brown measure I could find were in research papers.  I just posted in stackexchange.

Comment: Actually, it might be better to do it differently. I'll answer at MSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the two-sided shift is a normal operator this is not really a question about the Brown measure, but about the spectral measure, so it suffices to compute the $*$-moments $\tau(L^nL^{*m})$. For an introduction to Brown measure you might also see Chapter 11 of the book
https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/speicher/publikationen/Mingo-Speicher.pdf